# Combining the state monad with the costate comonad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, category-theory, comonad

How to combine the state monad `S -> (A, S)` with the costate comonad `(E->A, E)`?

I tried with both obvious combinations `S -> ((E->A, E), S)` and `(E->S->(A, S), E)` but then in either case I do not know how to define the operations (`return`, `extract`, ... and so on) for the combination.

Comment: You mean this is supposed to be a monad _and_ comonad then? Seems a bit optimistic to me, to think that ought to be possible...

Comment: @leftaroundabout : In fact I expect someone might have an answer using a so-called distributive law of a comonad over a monad (although I am not so sure how to use such beast).

Comment: There's no particular reason to believe (a) compositions of monads are monads, (b) compositions of comonads are comonads, or (c) any type at all is both monadic and comonadic (note that Identity is, note how extreme that is). So, expecting the composition of monad and a comonad to be either monadic or comonadic let alone both is quite adventurous. The distributive law would hold just if State CoState was the same as CoState State, which is neither true nor helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @J.Abrahamson. But, if I cannot combine them, how am I supposed to write a functional program that uses both a state and a costate?

Comment: @Bob, use them in different contexts, for what each is good for?  Your question sounds like 
"How do I write a functional program which uses both `Bool` and `Int` even though I can't combine them?"

Comment: When you talk about the distributive law between a monad and a comonad in the [Uustalu and Vene](http://www.ioc.ee/~tarmo/papers/cmcs08.pdf) sense you usually don't mean a monad and its particular dual comonad. And in that case you use a distributive law.

Comment: [This might be somewhat more accessible](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/03/transforming-comonad-with-monad.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining two monads `O` and `I` yields a monad if either `O` or `I` is copointed, i.e. have an `extract` method. Each comonad is copointed. If both `O` and I` are copointed, then you have two different "natural" ways to obtain a monad which are presumably not equivalent.

You have:

```
unit_O :: a -> O a
join_O :: O (O a) -> O a
unit_I :: a -> I a
join_I :: I (I a) -> I a
```

Here I've added `_O` and `_I` suffixed for clarity; in actual Haskell code, they would not be there, since the type checker figures this out on its own.

Your goal is to show that `O (I O (I a)))` is a monad. Let's assume that `O` is copointed, i.e. that there is a function `extract_O :: O a -> a`.

Then we have:

```
unit :: a -> O (I a)
unit = unit_O . unit_I
join :: O (I (O (I a))) -> O (I a)
```

The problem, of course, is in implementing `join`. We follow this strategy:

- `fmap` over the outer `O`
- use `extract_O` to get ride of the inner `O`
- use `join_I` to combine the two `I` monads

This leads us to

```
join = fmap_O $ join_I . fmap_I extract
```

To make this work, you'll also need to define

```
newtype MCompose O I a = MCompose O (I a)
```

and add the respective type constructors and deconstructors into the definitions above.

The other alternative uses `extract_I` instead of `extract_O`. This version is even simpler:

```
join = join_O . fmap_O extract_I
```

This defines a new monad. I assume you can define a new comonad in the same way, but I haven't attempted this.

Comment: Concretely, what do we get when we apply this general result to the state monad and the costate comonad?

Comment: Nice presentation! By the way is there a copointed Functor in Haskell which cannot be a Comonad?

Comment: I'm trying to prove any natural monoidal structure on `forall r.F(r)->r` (natural on F) for a copointed Functor F induces a comonad on F. Do you think this is true?

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer demonstrates, both of the combinations `S -> ((E->A, E), S)` and `(E->S->(A, S), E)`
have Monad and Comonad instances simultaneously. In fact giving a Monad/Comonad instance is
equivalent to giving a
monoid structure to resp. its *points* ∀r.r->f(r) or its *copoints* ∀r.f(r)->r, at least in classical,
non-constructive sense (I don't know the constructive answer). This fact suggests that actually a
Functor f has a very good chance that it can
be both Monad and Comonad, provided its points and copoints are non-trivial.

The real question, however, is whether the Monad/Comonad instances constructed as such do have natural
computational/categorical meanings. In this particular case I would say "no", because you don't seem to have
*a priori* knowledge about how to compose them in a way that suit your computational needs.

The standard categorical way to compose two (co)monads is via adjunctions. Let me summarize your situation:

```
      Fₑ         Fₛ
      -->       -->
Hask  ⊣   Hask  ⊣ Hask
      <--       <--
      Gₑ         Gₛ

Fₜ(a) = (a,t)
Gₜ(a) = (t->a)
```

Proof of Fₜ ⊣ Gₜ:

```
Fₜ(x) -> y   ≃
(x,t) -> y   ≃
x  -> (t->y) ≃
x  -> Gₜ(y)
```

Now you can see that the state monad (s->(a,s)) ≃ (s->a,s->s) is the composition GₛFₛ and the costate comonad
is FₑGₑ. This adjunction says that Hask can be interpreted as a model of the (co)state (co)algebras.

Now, 'adjunctions compose.' For example,

```
FₛFₑ(x) -> y ≃
Fₑ(x)   -> Gₛ(y) ≃
x       -> GₑGₛ(y)
```

So FₛFₑ ⊣ GₑGₛ. This gives a pair of a monad and a comonad, namely

```
T(a) = GₑGₛFₛFₑ(a)
     = GₑGₛFₛ(a,e)
     = GₑGₛ(a,e,s)
     = Gₑ(s->(a,e,s))
     = e->s->(a,e,s)
     = ((e,s)->a, (e,s)->(e,s))

G(a) = FₛFₑGₑGₛ(a)
     = FₛFₑGₑ(s->a)
     = FₛFₑ(e->s->a)
     = Fₛ(e->s->a,e)
     = (e->s->a,e,s)
     = ((e,s)->a, (e,s))
```

T is simply the state monad with the state (e,s), G is the costate comonad with the costate (e,s), so
these do have very natural meanings.

Composing adjunctions is a natural, frequent mathematical operation. For example, a *geometric morphism*
between topoi (kind of Cartesian Closed Categories which admit complex (non-free) constructions at the 'type level') is defined as a pair of adjunctions, only requiring its left adjoint to be *left exact* (i.e. preserves finite limits). If those topoi are sheaves on topological spaces,
composing the adjunctions simply corresponds to composing (unique) continuous base change maps (in the opposite direction), having a very natural meaning.

On the other hand, composing monads/comonads directly seems to be a very rare practice in Mathematics.
This is because often a (co)monad is thought of as a carrier of an (co)algebraic theory, rather than as a
model. In this interpretation the corresponding adjunctions *are* the models, not the monad. The problem
is that composing two theories requires another theory, a theory about how to compose them. For example,
imagine composing two theories of monoids. Then you may get at least two new theories,
namely the theory of lists of lists, or ring-like algebras where two kinds of binary operations distribute.
Neither is *a priori* better/more natural than the other. This is the meaning of "monads don't compose"; it doesn't say the composition cannot be a monad, but it does say you will need another theory how to compose them.

In contrast, composing adjunctions naturally results in another adjunction simply because by doing so you are
implicity specifying the rules of composing two given theories. So by taking the monad of the composed adjunction you get the theory that also specifies the rules of composition.